# Why does Apple use Obj-C for their internal code rather than Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I was doing some coding today and I created a class in Swift for one of my viewcontrollers. I forgot to tie my class to my viewcontroller so when I opened up assistant editor it gave me the generic viewcontroller base class.

here [image: image 1]

And I noticed that it appears to be in Obj-C. (I've never studied Obj-C before I am just guessing based on some other code in Obj-C I've seen previously)

why does Apple use Obj-C instead of Swift. I thought Apples official language was Swift and I thought Apple did this really big push to get Obj-C developers to use Swift instead of Obj-C.

If Swift is supposed to be a better version of Obj-C and with Swift 4 we can do nearly everything in Swift that Obj-C can do why doesn't Apple just convert over to Swift and outdate Obj-C(I understand it will take time and money to do and its not just gonna happen overnight)

It seems to me that Swift would be way simpler to learn then Obj-C for beginners (i know because i learned it in like 2 months) and Swift is less complicated and better laid out then Obj-C

I know that Swift is buggy as HECK I run into bugs everyday but ill bet Obj-C was even worse when it started out (benefits of hindsight) so in a couple of years Swift will be equal or greater than Obj-C keeping its basic simplicity as well

and if i am wrong about this please correct me

Comment: in spite of _ObjC_ is 30+ years old and _Swift_ is only 4 years only, Apple currently supports __both__ _ObjC_ and _Swift_ on the same way; the `Foundation` classes and `UIKit` are based on _ObjC_ currently.

Comment: UIViewController dates from 2007, before Swift. Apple doesn't have a magic wand to convert all existing Objective-C code to Swift. It takes time.

Comment: I understand that conversions take time. I hate it when my teacher makes us convert C++ programs into Swift. it just seems weird that Apple is all for this language Swift and yet they still use Obj-C. and I understand that Obj-C is a cool language but it seems a little out-dated. Its like slapping icing onto a really old cake

Comment: It is not possible. It is simply impossible to write a responder chain in Swift. It is simply impossible to write a generic undo manager in Swift.  … If one say, it is possible, please give me the code. Both concepts can be written with a few lines of code in Objective-C. It is not too much to translate to Swift, it dos not take too much time to translate to Swift. It is impossible to translate it to Swift.

Comment: @holex - no, Foundation in Swift it is thing in itself. It is not Foundation from objc. As for UIKit - you are right.

Comment: Not anymore .

Answer (score 4):

There are several core concepts in Cocoa, which are simply impossible to implement in Swift. My favorite is the responder chain. Try to do that in Swift …

Every early binding, statically typing language needs a dynamic door opener to be able to build up a framework for GUI apps. For Swift this is Objective-C. Swift without Objective-C would simply not work.

Therefore Swift has never been called the "official language". And ask some guys on the AppKit team, what they would answer.

Answer (score 3):

That's because Objective-C came way before Swift.

Rewriting every Foundation and UIKit classes from Objective-C to Swift would take a long time and require a lot of testing just to replace something that has been in production for decades and just works.

Answer (score 2):

It gets down to chronology.

`macOS`, formerly called `OS X` (pronounced "OS Ten"), was released in 2001 after a public beta in 2000. It's API roots lie in NeXT (all those NS-prefixed classes) which began in 1985.

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS)

> The heritage of what would become macOS had originated at NeXT, a
>   company founded by Steve Jobs following his departure from Apple in
>   1985. There, the Unix-like NeXTSTEP operating system was developed, and then launched in 1989. The kernel of NeXTSTEP is based upon the
>   Mach kernel, which was originally developed at Carnegie Mellon
>   University, with additional kernel layers and low-level user space
>   code derived from parts of BSD. Its graphical user interface was built
>   on top of an object-oriented GUI toolkit using the Objective-C
>   programming language.

iOS (or if you will, UIKit) was released in 2008, one year after the original iPhone.

And Swift? Version 1 was released in 2014. At this point in time I'd wager (and probably win the bet) that Apple employs more ObjC coders than Swift. I might even wager that *all* code in High Sierra and iOS 11 was written in ObjC.

Apple understands how slowly things should evolve. They had OS X running on Intel chips years before they announced the transition from PowerPC to Intel. They were "using" Swift in some places a few years before they announced it. It's quite possible that they *are* working on a Swift-based UIKit - and have been for a few years.

But commercially releasing such a monster transition? Likely years away. Particularly if you consider (1) the open-source nature of Swift, (2) it's rapidly evolving nature, and (3) the lack of an ABI - which is due out in about a year.

Comment: Switching to Swift would improve the productivity and speed of Swift. Making it so that Xcode no longer has to do all of those conversions. Assuming that at least 50% of Xcode runs internally on Obj-C they would have to rewrite Xcode basically as a new Application which will take time and money

Comment: and you are right because of the rapidly updating Swift language Apple will probably stick with Obj-C for at least the next 5 years i was just curious why Apple used Obj-C internally when you can basically do with Swift everything Obj-C can do.

Comment: "Basically do with Swift everything ObjC can do..." Tool support for Swift is literally decades behind. Compile times are dramatically longer. Breaking changes to the syntax and stdlib are accepted as a "cost of business". Swift has lots going for it, but it's still immature.

Comment: As well, Swift's ABI is not stable.